# How to burn iso to usb stick on Mac?

Tags: terminal, windows, iso

I did check [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=burn+iso) search result but would like to bring this up in a new question since it has been at least 6-7 years since the latest question in a similar category: How can I burn the Windows 11 iso to a USB flash drive on a Mac?

I have Macbook Pro, 13-in 2020, macOS: Ventura 13.1.

I searched online for solutions and tried a great number of them, including:

- Etcher (third-party software)
- UNetbootin (third-party software that was unable to open)
- WonderISO (third-party software)
- Virtualbox (errors occurred as it tried to set up the Windows virtualbox)
- Disk Utility (does not contain the tools mentioned in the resource I was following at the time)
- Terminal
- UUByte ISO Editor

Terminal was the closest to working, but once I plugged it into my computer it claimed it was missing a file so it's likely the process was corrupted.

UUByte had the best review in the most recent how-to resource, but it required a purchase. I still ended up buying it, but not only was their email considered junk, but the code coming from the purchase also did not work either.

[Here](https://www.sysgeeker.com/burn-iso-to-usb-on-mac.html) is one of the sources (2020) I received information from. I checked a couple of others, but so far none have worked.

If there's also a factual answer saying how it is definitely not possible anymore, with any solution, I'll accept that.

Comment: An ISO is an optical disk (CD/DVD) image. A USB drive is a disk drive. You can’t just force an optical drive image onto a  different medium. Why not download the Win11 bootable USB image?

Comment: @Allan I have tried your first suggestion: It did not work (not on the new computer). For your second, I read [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11), it includes USB flash drive. Am I mistaking what it means?